# Missing Parameter in PHP $_POST Function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter to pass some parameters to my PHP page through `$_POST` request, and in the PHP page I am reading.

```
$foo = $this->input->post('myParam');
```

If the `myParam` parameter is present in the `$_POST` request, then `$foo` will be assigned the `myParam` value. How do I check if `myParam` is **not passed**  in the `$_POST` request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Googled 'codeigniter input post'.

First result is [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

From that document:

> ```
> $this->input->post('some_data');
> ```
>
> The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to
>   retrieve does not exist.

So you need to do:

```
if ($foo===false) {
   // do something if it's not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use the form validation class to do pre-processing on your data. This is documented [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

You'd do something like:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('myParam', 'myParam', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}
```

If your validation fails it will send you back to the form and you'll have to re-populate it with data, there is a way to do this (see the doc). If it passes you can then be sure that `$this->input->post('myParam');` will return a value.